# Retrieve SD Card Serial Number and Manufacturer under Linux

Tags: java, linux, ide, sd-card, scsi

I want to be able to retrieve an SD Card's Serial Number, Manufacturer, and any other information it may provide.  Java or just a command to run would be great.  [Compact Framework does it](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2009/03/31/getting-an-sd-card-serial-number-in-the-compact-framework/), but that doesn't help me.

Comment: This is with a native mmc driver, right?  (i.e. Not a USB-SD adapter).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but I believe in my case, yes it is mmc (Android phone).  There is no USB in this case, but I recall some instance where there wasn't a USB port, but the way the reader was connected to the device actually used USB.  I can't remember exactly what that was though.

I haven't gotten a chance to test the answers below (too many projects), but they both look promising.

Comment: http://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/sd-memory-card-faq/reading-sd-card-cid-serial-psn-internal-numbers/

Answer (score 4):

You can also try

```
sudo hwinfo --disk
```

to get information on your disks, including SD Cards.

hdparm -i may not work through sdcard controllers

Comment: I didn't know about hwinfo, so that's interesting.  However, the output (for a USB-SD adapter) doesn't show anything specific about the SD card.  Probably it's not possible without native mmc, so maybe this is a good answer.

Comment: Is "Unique ID:" reliable ?

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to get some info out of "hdparm"

```
hdparm -i /dev/sda
```

Gives a bunch of info about /dev/sda which includes its serial number. In my test case, this was a hard drive, but presumably the same may work for a SD card (which looks a lot like a disk to the OS)

Comment: doesnt either using rts5139 adapter